# SQL database design using a logical ER

Tags: mysql, sql, database, entity-relationship, erd

I am very (very!) new to database design and using entity relationship models and I have a very rookie question (probably that's why i could not find an answer)

So i am designing a database for journals which have keywords, theories used, topics, subtopics, research questions, outcomes, aims... So far i have figured it is a many-to-many relationship? is that correct? e.g. one paper can have many keywords and one keyword can be used in many papers?

If that's true then i will have an associative entity to handle this, but do i need one for each single entity or there is a way to circumvent that for a better design? e.g. many `authors(PK AuthordID)` write many `papers (PK PaperID)` then I have a  `PaperByAuthor(PK,FK AuthorID, PK,FK PaperID)`. Can i connect this entity to keywords, topics etc as it represents this one paper? or this is a completely wrong idea and i should create associative entities connected to Paper for each of them?

Thanks very much! Bit embarrassed by the question but still learning!

Answer (score 1):

Even though i'm not sure i fully understood your entities relationships, I would recommend thinking of the use-cases.

Even if the same entities could be grouped in different ways, if you think about what you would want to display or how would you use the data most often, the relations would be clearer.

After you identified the right relationships, try going through the first 3 [normal forms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization).
Most of the time you end up with a really good design after that.

Next would be optimising the structure for queries but that is a different story.

Also, if you have a lot of many-to-many relationships, take a look at noSQL Document Databases. Or use SQL but make fields that store JSON data (this technique is a bit complicated and not always good).

Answer (score 1):

From a logical design perspective - your ER diagram - you should definitely have separate entity type for each aspect.  Taking some examples from your question there should be a `Paper` entity type, an `Author` entity type and a `PaperByAuthor` entity type which associates those two and only those two.  `PaperKeyword` and 'PaperTopic` etc. should each be their own entity type.

The physical table design should also have one table per associative entity type.  As proof, think about the alternative where a single table does everything.  One column in this table would be `PaperID`.  Fair enough.  The other column - what would it be?  `KeywordTheoryTopicSubtopicResearchQuestionOutcomeAimID`?  Then you have to ensure all your other table (`Keyword`, `Author` etc.) never have a primary key value which also appears in the primary key of any other.  If you add a third column to the association table to show which data table it points, every query you ever write becomes a huge `if RefersTo = 'Author' read from Author` rat's nest or you end up joining every table every time and ignoring columns from the other tables.

No.  Individual association tables is the only way to go.

Answer (score 0):

A many-to-many relation in an ER-Model is represented like this in your Logical Model:

```
Author(AuthordID {PK})
Paper(PaperID {PK})
PaperAuthor(PaperAuthorID {PK}, AuthorID {FK}, FK PaperID {FK})
```

There's no need to combine this with other relations, unless there is actually the rare situation there there is a threeway relation. In this case the relation Paper-Author could only exist iff the relations Paper-X and Author-X also exist.

Only such a situation would justify:

```
PaperAuthorX(PaperAuthorID {PK}, AuthorID {FK}, FK PaperID {FK}, xID {FK})
```